# How do I compare the order of two lists in R?

Tags: r, comparison, ranking, rank

Hi I'm trying to determine the change in ordering of two lists in R.

e.g. Comparing rankings of tennis players from two different months.

```
Feb <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Mar <- c("D", "B", "C", "A")

orderChange(Feb, Mar)
```

I would like to get a result which shows the difference in ordering/ranking.

```
(-3, 0, 0, 3)
```

I've tried which() but that only tells me whether an element is present and doesn't compare the ordering.

```
which(Mar %in% Feb)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Maybe `seq_along(Feb) - match(Feb, Mar)` ? What will be the expected result in case of `Mar <- c("C", "B", "D", "A")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `seq_along` and subtract `match`.

```
Feb <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
Mar <- c("D", "B", "C", "A")
Apr <- c("C", "B", "D", "A")

seq_along(Feb) - match(Feb, Mar)
#[1] -3  0  0  3

seq_along(Feb) - match(Feb, Apr)
#[1] -3  0  2  1
```

and can pack this in a function if needed.

```
orderChange <- function(x, y) seq_along(x) - match(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you GKi! Really appreciate it.